# How to check status code of response changed to json?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, response

i have a question. I am doing rtsp client tests. This Client is our, works preety nice. Question is, is exist a way to check status of response if it return in json?

client.py

```
def get_paths(self):
   return requests.get(f"{self.API_URL}/v1/paths/list").json()
```

tests.py

```
def test_get_path(self):
    response = self.rtsp_client.get_paths()
    self.assertEqual(response, 200)
```

In this example , i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oliwer/Documents/repozytoriumGit/device-channels/project/backend/rtsp_simple_server_api/tests.py", line 99, in test_get_path
    self.assertEqual(response, 200)
AssertionError: {'items': {'none': {'confName': 'none', '[3105 chars][]}}} != 200
```

I understand why i got this output. I am just interested is exist a way to test status code of this response.

Ps. The point is that, i can't change request functionality, it has to return json, i wanted to get something like that:

tests.py

```
    def test_get_path(self):
       response = self.rtsp_client.get_path().command_that_can_reverse_json()_command
       self.assertEqual(response, 200)
```

I thought, that it is possible, when i have .json() method. In my opinion response is an object with this first response, but encoded to json file. So my thoughts were that i can reverse this operation, but i did not know how. In your opinion, i can't do that.

Comment: Parse the JSON?

Comment: You're not returning the response code in any way from the function, so: no. Change the function to return something else that does include the status code; or check the code inside the function and raise an exception if it's not 200.

Comment: @Scott OP already does so.

Comment: Parsing , mean json.loads() not works properly, i think that i will use it @deceze. You can have right, that i am returning json, not response, so it is not possible to reverse this json() command, to get clear response object ;(. It is most important to return json there not response for other functionality. The best option may be to check status code inside client function. Thanks all

Comment: I would like to give you some check , or thanks by these comments, but i am new here, and i dont know how to do that :(

Comment: Well, you get a cake. You take a slice out of that cake and throw the rest away. Can you get the whole cake back from this one slice? No.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you change your code like this

```
def get_paths():
   return requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
```

than you can access the status_code of the response with:

```
r = get_paths()
print(r.status_code)
>>> 200
```

Comment: I know that. the point is that request has to be build like that, i can't change request functionalities, but i can add raise exeption inside, what i will do. Anyway thanks for answer